# How to access atributes in a list inside a list (Python) for a Dag in AirFlow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have the following piece of code in a Dag on Airflow:

```
scenery= {
        'task_id': 'TASK_ID',
        'name': 'TASK-NAME-TEMPLATE',
        'job_class_name': '.com.company.project.ClassName',
        'template': 'ClassName'
    }
    
    stores = [
        {'name': 'STORE-NAME', 'jobs': [{'job': scenery, 'days': 2}, {'job': scenery, 'days': 1}]},
        {'name': 'ANOTHE-STORE-NAME', 'jobs': [{'job': scenery, 'days': 2}, {'job': scenery, 'days': 3}]}
    ]
    
    for store in stores:
        for job in store.jobs:
            dag_scenery_template = KubernetesPodOperator(
                task_id=store.name + job.task_id + '_template',
                name=store.name + job.name,
                namespace='default',
                image=image,
                arguments=[job.job_class_name,
                           '--runner=DataflowRunner', store.name, job.days],
                secrets=[secrets],
                tolerations=Tolerations.default,
                affinity=Affinity.default,
                resources=resources,
                dag=dag)
    
            dag_scenery = DataflowTemplateOperator(
                task_id=store.name+ '_cip_installment_payment',
                template=job.template,
                dag=dag)
```

When Cloud Build on GCP finish deploy for my application i have this error on main page of Airflow:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/name-of-dag.py] 'dict' object has no attribute 'jobs'
```

How can access this attributes ?

Tanks guys!

Comment: Wrong with `for job in store.jobs:`, should be `for job in store['jobs']:`

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a dictionary in Python is different from accessing a JSON object in JS.

For example, correct jobs as follows:

```
 for store in stores:
    for job in store['jobs']:
        ...
```